# Write to /dev/null?

Tags: external-files, package-writing

I'm working on package that (among other things) writes an external file during compilation. I'd like to provide an option to the package to *not* write the external file.

I know I can set up a boolean and test for it everywhere in the package the writes take place.  But it would be nice to just set the `openout` command at the beginning to write to `/dev/null` or its equivalent.

Is that possible? I need to keep this package supported on Windows, Mac, and Unix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The writing is probably done by `\immediate\write\STREAM{...}`; I usually define a macro to stand for `\immediate\write` so its meaning can be changed at will

```
...
\newif\iftim@write
\DeclareOption{nowrite}{\tim@writefalse}
\DeclareOption{write}{\tim@writetrue}
...
\ExecuteOptions{...,nowrite}% or write, if you prefer
\ProcessOptions\relax
...

\iftim@write
  \def\tim@write{\immediate\write}
\else
  \let\tim@write\@gobbletwo
\fi
```

This code is for the case where your writing operations are done or not via a package option.

If the boolean is true, `\tim@write\STREAM{...}` would be expanded to `\immediate\write\STREAM{...}`; if the boolean is false, the same tokens would become `\@gobbletwo\STREAM{...}`, so `\STREAM` and `{...}` will vanish.

Comment: That is an elegant solution @egreg. I love its simplicity! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The command `\nofiles` switches off all file writing LaTeX

Comment: It switches off the writing of files that use `\protected@write`.

Comment: And also disables creation of index and glossary.

Comment: @andrey-virhov yes, this is the intended behavior